# Hello, I have a question for Pine Script rsi / ema

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I have a question for the pine script.

When the rsi is 30
If the ta.crossover (ema20, ema50) appears between 1 and 3 candle closures, enter the Long strategy,

When rsi is 70
Is it possible to enter the short strategy if the ta.crossunder (ema20, ema50) comes out between 1 and 3 candle close?

```
//@version=5
strategy("new_strategy", overlay=true, margin_long=100, margin_short=100)


// ema200


ema20 = ta.ema(close, 20)
ema50 = ta.ema(close, 50)


emalong = ta.crossover(ema20,ema50)

emashort = ta.crossunder(ema20,ema50)


//rsi

ma(source, length, type) =>
    switch type
        "SMA" => ta.sma(source, length)
        "Bollinger Bands" => ta.sma(source, length)
        "EMA" => ta.ema(source, length)
        "SMMA (RMA)" => ta.rma(source, length)
        "WMA" => ta.wma(source, length)
        "VWMA" => ta.vwma(source, length)

rsiLengthInput = input.int(14, minval=1, title="RSI Length", group="RSI Settings")
rsiSourceInput = input.source(close, "Source", group="RSI Settings")
maTypeInput = input.string("SMA", title="MA Type", options=["SMA", "Bollinger Bands", "EMA", "SMMA (RMA)", "WMA", "VWMA"], group="MA Settings")
maLengthInput = input.int(14, title="MA Length", group="MA Settings")
bbMultInput = input.float(2.0, minval=0.001, maxval=50, title="BB StdDev", group="MA Settings")

up = ta.rma(math.max(ta.change(rsiSourceInput), 0), rsiLengthInput)
down = ta.rma(-math.min(ta.change(rsiSourceInput), 0), rsiLengthInput)
rsi = down == 0 ? 100 : up == 0 ? 0 : 100 - (100 / (1 + up / down))
rsiMA = ma(rsi, maLengthInput, maTypeInput)
isBB = maTypeInput == "Bollinger Bands"





rsilong = ta.crossover(rsi,30)

rsishort = ta.crossunder(rsi,70)



longCondition = 
if (longCondition)
    strategy.entry("My Long Entry Id", strategy.long)



shortCondition = 
if (shortCondition)
    strategy.entry("My Short Entry Id", strategy.short)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure you can do that. The ema cross is your trigger condition. Therefore, when that happens, you need to use the `ta.barssince()` function to see when `RSI > 70` or `RSI < 30` happened.

I set the number of bars since the `RSI < 30` to 10 just to show you an example.

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script", overlay=true)

ema20 = ta.ema(close, 20)
ema50 = ta.ema(close, 50)
rsi_val = ta.rsi(close, 14)

plot(ema20, color=color.green)
plot(ema50, color=color.red)

plotchar(rsi_val, "RSI", "")

ema_long_cross = ta.crossover(ema20, ema50)
rsi_long_condition = rsi_val < 30
rsi_long_barssince = ta.barssince(rsi_long_condition)

buy_condition = ema_long_cross and (rsi_long_barssince > 0) and (rsi_long_barssince <= 10)

plotshape(ema_long_cross)
plotshape(buy_condition, "Buy", shape.labelup, location.belowbar, color.green, 0, "Buy", color.white)
```

[image]